# Validating each value of a list using WTForms

Tags: flask, wtforms

Using `WTForms`, I ask the user to enter two *numbers* that will be further used on a simple calculation. Those *numbers* both need to be validated.

I have defined the following **form**

```
class AForm(Form):
    ff=DecimalField(default=0.0, validators=[NumberRange(min=0, max=2)])
```

**The template**

```
<form action="/test" method=post>
    {% for L in entries %}
        {{ render_field(form.ff) }}
    {% endfor %}
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="calc">
</form>
```

**The Flask view**

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_form():
    entries=[0, 1]
    form = AForm(request.form)
    ff_l=request.form.getlist('ff')
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        L=0
        v=0
        a=0
        b=0
        for L,v in enumerate(ff_l):
            a=float(v)
            b+=a
        return render_template('res.html', b=b)
    return render_template('test.html', entries=entries, form=form)
```

I am aware I am using the `getlist` method, which is not part of `WTForms`, but this is the only solution found so far, since, by doing `ff_l=form.ff.data`, I would get a `dict` with only one value per field and not the whole list, associated to the given field.

Problems start when I want to validate submitted values: the `form.validate()` method will only validate the first value of the list, while the second will not be subjected to any validation.

**My question**: how is it possible to validate each value of a list ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to use [`FieldList`](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.FieldList) to let WTForms know there can be more than one entry:

```
field = DecimalField(default=0.0, validators=[NumberRange(min=0, max=2)])

class AForm(Form):
    ff = FieldList(field)
```

Then you should be able to simply set the data in the form constructor:

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_form():
    entries=[0, 1]
    form = AForm(request.form, ff=entries)
    ff_l = form.ff.data
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        result = sum(ff_l)
        return render_template('res.html', b=result)
    return render_template('test.html', form=form)
```

And your template should now loop over the subfields in `form.ff`:

```
<form action="/test" method=post>
    {% for field in form.ff %}
        {{ render_field(field) }}
    {% endfor %}
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="calc">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks ! one more sub-question: would you please explain `form = AForm(request.form, ff=entries)`? More particularly, what about `ff=entries`: for `FieldList` you must yield the number of entries, is that correct ?

Comment: `ff=entries` *should* set the entries when there is no data provided in `request.form` for `ff` - otherwise, since the minimum number of entries is 0, no fields will show up.  If you always want a minimum number of entries you can change `ff`'s declaration to specify a minimum number of fields `ff = FieldList(field, min=3)` (for example)

Comment: Yes that works... just replaced `min `with `min_entries` in the `FieldList` definition.